# AngularJS loading when using $http

Tags: angularjs

When I pull data back from my API I want to display a loading gif.
There are some cases where I connect to multiple resources on the same view, and I don't want to use an $http interceptor, so I was creating my views like this:

```
.controller('ViewOrderController', ['$routeParams', 'OrderService', 'AccountService', function (params, orderService, accountService) {
    var self = this;

    self.orderNumber = params.orderNumber;
    self.loadingAccounts = true;
    self.loadingOrders = true;
    self.order = {};
    self.account = {};

    orderService.get(self.orderNumber, false).then(function (response) {
        self.order = response.data;
        self.loadingOrders = false;

        accountService.get(self.order.accountNumber).then(function (response) {
            self.account = response.data;
            self.loadingOrders = false;
        });
    });
}])
```

but this soon got messy, because there were some instances where I would be connecting to 4 or 5 difference resources.
My first response was to separate each call into it's own controller, so it would look a bit like this:

```
.controller('OrderController', ['$routeParams', 'OrderService', 'AccountService', function (params, orderService, accountService) {
    var self = this;

    self.loading = true;
    self.orderNumber = params.orderNumber;
    self.order = {};

    orderService.get(self.orderNumber, false).then(function (response) {
        self.order = response.data;
        accountService.accountNumber = self.order.accountNumber; // Bind the account number to the service for use later
        self.loading = false;
    });
}])

.controller('AccountController', ['$scope', 'AccountService', function (scope, service) {
    var self = this;

    self.loading = true;
    self.account = {};

    scope.$watch(function () {
        return service.accountNumber;
    }, function (accountNumber) {
        if (accountNumber) {
            service.get(accountNumber).then(function (response) {
                self.account = response.data;
                self.loading = false;
            });
        }
    });
}])
```

but then I started running into problems of repetition:

```
.controller('RecentOrdersController', ['OrderService', function (service) {
    var self = this; // store our controller in a variable

    self.loading = true; // This is what the ajax loading gif looks at to see if it should be displayed
    self.orders = []; // Our orders array

    service.recent(30).then(function (response) { // Get the 30 most recent orders
        for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
            var order = response.data[i]; // Store the order in a variable (for use later)
            var desciption = service.getDescription(order); // Get our description

            order.description = desciption; // Set our order description
            self.orders.push(order); // Push our order to our array
        }

        self.loading = false; // Set our loading flag to false (hide the ajax loading gif);
    });
}])

.controller('SyncFailureOrdersController', ['OrderService', function (service) {
    var self = this; // store our controller in a variable

    self.loading = true; // This is what the ajax loading gif looks at to see if it should be displayed
    self.orders = []; // Our orders array

    service.syncFailures(30).then(function (response) { // Get the 30 most sync failures
        for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
            var order = response.data[i]; // Store the order in a variable (for use later)
            var desciption = service.getDescription(order); // Get our description

            order.description = desciption; // Set our order description
            self.orders.push(order); // Push our order to our array
        }

        self.loading = false; // Set our loading flag to false (hide the ajax loading gif);
    });
}])
```

My last post, someone said to put my shared code into services and this is what I want to do.
I would like to create a service that will tell the controller when it is loading or when it is complete for each call made on it. I have no idea how to approach this though. Also, I have seen (after hours of searching) people using $resource; is there any need for this? Does it make the job easier?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update 1**

Thanks to @tommes I have updated his fiddle to show exactly what I am after:

https://jsfiddle.net/2mhq9crf/3/

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general method for composing asynchronous operations in angularjs is **promises** (**$q**)

You should probably put your api calls in services (my personal service preference is `.factory(...)`)

See this example:

https://jsfiddle.net/2mhq9crf/

### JS

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.factory('myService', function($timeout, $q) {
    // Stub of $http.get(...)
    return function () {
        var d = $q.defer();
        $timeout(function () {
            d.resolve("val!");
        }, 1000);
        return d.promise;
    };
});

myApp.factory('myOtherService', function($timeout, $q) {
    // Stub of $http.get(...)
    return function () {
        var d = $q.defer();
        $timeout(function () {
            d.resolve("val!");
        }, 500);
        return d.promise;
    };
});


myApp.controller("MyCtrl", function ($scope, myService, myOtherService) {
    $scope.loading = [];
    $scope.vals = [];

    // Add loading-specific promise-handlers
    var loadThisPromise = function (p) {
        // Add the promise to our list of loading promises
        $scope.loading.push(p);

        p.finally(function () {
            // .finally is called even if the request fails

            // Remove the promise from our list of loading
            // promises, using object identity
            $scope.loading.splice($scope.loading.indexOf(p), 1);
        });

        // Return promise for further promise handling
        return p;
    };

    // Produce a function that always logs the given text
    var logThis = function (str) {
        return function (val) {
            console.log(str);

            // Remember to forward value for promise chaining
            return val;
        };
    };

    // Promise handler for pushing a value to the scope
    var pushVal = function (val) {
        $scope.vals.push(val);
        return val;
    };

    // Add loading-specific promise-handlers and 
    // work with the promise from there
    loadThisPromise(myService())
        .then(pushVal)
        .then(logThis("myService loaded!"));
    loadThisPromise(myOtherService())
        .then(pushVal)
        .then(logThis("myOtherService loaded!"));
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
});
```

### HTML

```
<body ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <h2>Hello, {{name}}!</h2>
        <tt style="color: red;" ng-show="loading.length > 0">LOADING...</tt>
        <pre ng-bind="vals | json"></pre>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Update 1**

In the case of multiple lists on the same page with individual lists and loading statusses, I would reuse the controller function like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/2mhq9crf/4/

```
app.controller("AccountCtrl", ["OrderService", function (OrderService) {
    ControllerFun.call(this, OrderService);
}]);
```

If you want to have a combined loading status in the parent controller, you should share the combined loading state via a service.

Hope it helps :-)

**Update 2**

Here's a solution with a data service managing **loading** state as well as the response data by updating the data in-place: 
https://jsfiddle.net/2mhq9crf/8/

This is more or less how `$resource` works.

Comment: Your answer is clever and really close to what I want. I have updated my question with a fiddle example (using yours)

Comment: thanks, not to be a pain, but is there any way to not use a reusable controller and perhaps create a service instead?

Comment: Everything is possible :-) Which part would you like the service to help with?

Comment: I have tried to have a go myself: https://jsfiddle.net/2mhq9crf/7/ but I am not getting it :)

Comment: I think you might be mixing responsibilites by having `ctrl.orders` be the data list for `ng-repeat` and the pseudo-promise responsible for the loading state (`ctrl.orders.loading`).
What about exporting an interface from the data service like: `{data: [], loading: true}`?
That way the data service could keep a reference to the response and update data in place.
Does this make any sense?

Comment: no :( I am new to angular, so this makes no sense to me

Comment: Ok, I've added an updated jsfiddle, using in-place updating of the return value from `DataService.loadData`

Comment: thank you, that is exactly what I was trying to do :D I nearly got there too!

Comment: It's sort of cheating, as it's hiding the asynchronous nature of the api request (`ctrl.orders = loadData(...)` looks synchronous), but it works :-)

Comment: It might be cheating, but it is the only way that (nicely) handles showing a loading gif. Unless there is another way, this is definitely the best solution for me.